# strange behaviour from loops in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, object, for-loop

I have a object like this:

```
{1:{x:21, y:54}, 2:{x:80,y:20}, ...}
```

and I want to compare an other x,y with my object x,y. if they are same I delete that x,y from my object. now when I do it like this:

```
  for(let i in myObj){
    if(myObj[i].x === info.x && myObj[i].y === info.y){
      delete myObj[i]
    }
  }
```

It works perfectly fine.

But when I do it like this:

```
  for(let i=0; i<=5; i++){
    if(myObj[i].x === info.x && myObj[i].y === info.y){
      delete myObj[i]
    }
  }
```

I get error from myObj[i].x:

> Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

My question is why my first approach doesn't work? I spend half of day thinking the problem is from somewhere else. I would appreciate a explanation.

Comment: Use the debugger.  Does `myObj[0]` exist?

Comment: Does your `myObj` object have the key `0`? Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser.

Comment: When you use for..in loop, you iterate over each item, not the index.

Comment: `for (let i = 1; ...` will probably work, because based on your exmaple object, there's no object with key `0` on it, the first key is `1`. (We are talking about `keys`, not `index`)

Comment: @Pavitra If by “item” you mean “value”, then that’s wrong. `for-in` iterates over keys. `for-of` iterates over `values`. A regular `for` loop iterates over numeric keys.

Comment: If you look at `i` in the first example, you'll find it's actually a string, like `"1"` and `"2"`, not a number, because objects don't use numbers for keys.

Comment: @HereticMonkey `var foo = {"1": "bar"}; console.log(foo[1]);` will print `"bar"` because the number used as an index will be automatically converted to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic difference between for and for...in loops is the way they iterate over. for loop iterates over through index values whereas for...in iterates over the items  present. Example :

```
var myObj = {
  firstObj : "first value",
  secondObj : "second value"
};

console.log(myObj[0]);     // undefined
console.log(myObj['firstObj']); //"first value"
console.log(myObj.firstObj);   //"first value"

var seconObj = [
  {
    a : "a value",
    a2 : "a2 value"
  },
  {
    b : "b value",
    b2 : "b2 value"
  }
];

console.log(seconObj[0].a); // "a value"
```